# Is it possible to favorite/bookmark Search API results using Flags or similar?

Tags: flags

We are using the Flag module to create favorites of Nodes and this works great for allowing users to bookmark specific Nodes.

The client also wants to bookmark search results from the Search API Views page.

Ideally, this would be with a Flag also but I don't see how this would be possible as the search result is simply a URL and not en entity.

How could we allow users to bookmark a URL/search-result? It doesn't have to be a Flag, if there is another way.

EDIT:

Found this module that works perfectly for our needs:

https://www.drupal.org/project/bookmarks

Comment: To clarify: “bookmark” does not mean “a web browser bookmark” in this question. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. By "bookmark", I mean simply to create a Drupal flag-type "bookmark" that is linked to the user account so that we can display "bookmarked" URLs from this Drupal website along site the "Flagged" nodes on the user's "Favorites" page.

Comment: Found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Found a module that works perfectly for our needs:

https://www.drupal.org/project/bookmarks